# Generate billing balance depending on the number of payments made

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is the table I have created and inserted values in it:

```
CREATE TABLE Invoices     
(
    InvID int,     
    InvAmount int
)
GO    
    
INSERT INTO Invoices 
VALUES (1, 543), (2, 749)

CREATE TABLE payments    
(
    PayID int IDENTITY (1, 1),     
    InvID int,     
    PayAmount int,    
    PayDate date
)

INSERT INTO payments
VALUES (1, 20, '2016-01-01'),
       (1, 35, '2016-01-07'),
       (1, 78, '2016-01-13'),
       (1, 52, '2016-01-25'),    
       (2, 40, '2016-01-03'),
       (2, 54, '2016-01-15'),  
       (2, 63, '2016-01-17'),
       (2, 59, '2016-01-28') 

SELECT * FROM Invoices 
SELECT * FROM payments
```

[image]

As shown in the screenshot above, the `Invoice` table specifies various customer billings (the first billing totals 543, the second billing totals 749).

[image]

As shown in the screenshot above, the `payments` table specifies the various payments the customer made for each of the billings. For example, one can see that on January 1st the customer paid 20 USD out of billing no. 1 (which totals 543 USD), and on January 3rd the customer paid 40 USD out of billing no. 2, (which totals 749 USD).

Now the question is:

Write a query that displays the billing balance, based on the number of payments made so far.

The query result should exactly look like the screenshot below:

[image]

This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT 
    payments.InvID,
    InvAmount - SUM(PayAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY payments.InvID ORDER BY PayID
                                     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 0 FOLLOWING) AS 'InvAmount',
    PayDate, PayAmount,
    InvAmount - SUM(PayAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY payments.InvID ORDER BY PayID) AS 'Balance'
FROM 
    Invoices
JOIN 
    payments ON payments.InvID = Invoices.InvID
```

After running the query, I got the following result which is shown below:

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot above, I nearly got the result I wanted.

The only problem is that `InvAmount` is exactly returning the same row values as `Balance`. I am not able to retain the starting row values of `InvAmount` which are 543 (`InvID = 1`) and 749 (`InvID = 2`) respectively.

How can this issue be solved?

Comment: Please do not use images for showing data... use formatted tabular text. And where you have helpfully provided DDL+DML you don't need to repeat that data in an image.

Comment: Also don't single quote your column aliases. Double quote or square brackets for SQL Server. (And thats only required if you use spaces, or reserved words).

Comment: For your `InvAmount`, just add back the `PayAmount`. `InvAmount + PayAmount - SUM(PayAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY payments.InvID ORDER BY PayID
                                     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 0 FOLLOWING) AS InvAmount`

Comment: or change to `BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING`. And handle `NULL` value using `ISNULL()` or `COALESCE()`

Comment: @Squirrel  InvAmount + PayAmount worked :)
You can include it in the answer section so that I can mark it as accepted :)

Comment: @Dale K ... If you could clarify on what exactly is 'formatted tabular text', it will be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Let me google that for you... how about this [how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add back the `PayAmount` in the calculation

```
InvAmount 
+ PayAmount
- SUM(PayAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY payments.InvID 
                           ORDER BY PayID
                                 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
                                          AND 0 FOLLOWING) AS InvAmount
```

Or use `BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING`. But you need to handle NULL value for the very first row

```
InvAmount 
- ISNULL(SUM(PayAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY payments.InvID 
                           ORDER BY PayID
                                 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
                                          AND 1 PRECEDING), 0) AS InvAmount
```

[db>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1db1d8525c9b87f0c0946afd0e191bc1)

Comment: `AND CURRENT ROW` is more usual than `AND 0 FOLLOWING`, but you could shorten that all to `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`

Answer (score 1):

You can use PARTITION BY clause for invoice identifier and then deduct the pay amount from the invoice amount as given below

```sql
;WITH CTE_Balance as
    (
    SELECT i.InvID, i.InvAmount, p.PayAmount, p.PayDate
         , InvAmount - sum(payamount) over (partition by p.invid order by paydate rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as balance 
         , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by p.invid order by p.paydate) as rnk
    FROM payments as p
    inner join Invoices as i
    on i.InvID = p.InvID
    )
    SELECT invid, case when rnk =1 then invamount else lag(balance) over(partition by invid order by paydate) end as invamount 
           ,payAmount, paydate, balance
    FROM CTE_Balance
```

| invid | invamount | payAmount | paydate | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 543 | 20 | 2016-01-01 | 523 |
| 1 | 523 | 35 | 2016-01-07 | 488 |
| 1 | 488 | 78 | 2016-01-13 | 410 |
| 1 | 410 | 52 | 2016-01-25 | 358 |
| 2 | 749 | 40 | 2016-01-03 | 709 |
| 2 | 709 | 54 | 2016-01-15 | 655 |
| 2 | 655 | 63 | 2016-01-17 | 592 |
| 2 | 592 | 59 | 2016-01-28 | 533 |

Comment: @DaleK, sorry. I did not notice that. I have corrected the query and updated the answer. Thanks for your extra eye on this.